# Referring to parent loop from a nested loop

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, nested-loops

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I have 2 tables in my db - 'regions' and 'distributors', both have a region_id column. What I want, is to:

1) iterate through the 'regions' table, for each region create a div with region_id as div id, then append a region_name to that div.

2) have a nested loop, which will iterate through the 'distributors' table, pull all the distributors that has the same region_id and then append it to the same div from stage 1.

So I tried this code:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php", {command:"get_regions"},
        function(result){
            var div_length = 786/result.length;
            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                var div_name = "div_region_"+result[i].region_id;
                $("<div id='"+div_name+"' class='div_region' 
                    style='width:"+div_length+"px; float:right;'></div>").appendTo("#content");

                $("<b>"+result[i].region_name+"</b></br>").appendTo("#"+div_name);
                $.getJSON("inc/API.php", {
                    command:"get_distributors", 
                    region_id: result[i].region_id
                },
                function(result){
                    for(var j=0; j<result.length; j++){
                        $("#"+div_name).append(result[j].distributor_name+"</br>");
                    }
                });
            }
     });
});
```

Though it creates the divs and appends region names to them, but the distributors names are all appended to the last div at the moment. Where's my mistake here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the loop has already completed before the AJAX function returns.

Change the second AJAX function to:

```
$.getJSON("inc/API.php", {
        command:"get_distributors", 
        region_id: result[i].region_id
    },
    function(result){
        for(var j=0; j<result.length; j++){
            var id = "#div_region_"+ result[j].region_id; //assuming that's how the data is structured
            $(id).append(result[j].distributor_name+"</br>");
        }
    });
```